# How to efficiently work on multiple machine learning and data science-related projects?

Tags: research-process, projects, time-management, work-life-balance

I am working on multiple projects on Machine Learning and Data Science. Is there any systematic way to work/manage projects to maximize efficiency in terms of getting things done while maintaining a work-life balance? Different projects are at different stages --- some are at the beginning stage, some are at the writing stage for publication --- require different types of involvements in terms of time and energy. Expert opinions are highly appreciated.

Comment: I think this is too personal for a general answer. Individuals do things differently. Some are driven by a schedule, others not.

Comment: I am sure this is personal but still learning from personal experience is not too bad I guess. Some people are very efficient in managing different research projects and would love to hear from them.

Comment: And any answer would depend on the definition of "efficiently". Why is efficiency important compared to, say, effectiveness?

Comment: Both 'efficiently' and 'effectiveness' is important. The ultimate goal is to get things done without hampering work-life balance.

Comment: This question is of the "boat programming" type (i.e. the problem of how to work on multiple projects is not restricted to academia), so I'm voting to close.

Comment: Work-life balance isn't clear from the question, and is, of course, different for everyone. Maybe you need to rework it. A better question might get some answers. I have my own methods, but they might not work for you.

Comment: @astronat : Does it matter if the question is not restricted to academia if the question is indeed relevant to academia?

Comment: It's relevant, but it's not a problem that's *specific* to academia, which is what we're interested in here. There are thousands of articles, blog posts, forums etc dedicated to productivity and project management, and I expect the vast majority of the proposed solutions will be applicable to academic work.